# I'm getting an error in java and mysql connectivity..its related to date comparing in java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, date, connectivity

```
String x=jTextField1.getText();
```

After connecting to the database the query is:

```
String query="INSERT INTO student(A) VALUES('"+a+"') where date=' " +x+ " ';";

stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

*a is a string which has a letter P assigned to it.

**The error** i am getting is "....check your mysql syntax....corresponding to the date='"+x'"; "

I want to compare the date entered in the textfield to the date in the mysql 'date' column and if it is correct,the 'a' value (which is P) should be written in column A in the same row of the date entered...

Please help...

Thank you...

Comment: The error i'm getting is: **You have an error in your sql syntax.Check your manual that correspond to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near 'where at='2012,02.20" at line 1 **

Comment: Use java.sql.`PreparedStatement`!

Answer (score 1):

I see a space after/before the single quote.

Furthermore `date` is also an SQL keyword, so better not use that as field name. You could write

```
`date`
```

---

***Addition***

Sorry, I realized that I erred (`date` cannot be a field queried as we are inserting a new record).
Either you mean:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO student(A) VALUES('P') WHERE CURRENT_DATE() = '2012-05-09'";
```

Or `date` is a field, and you just want to set another field:

```
String query = "UPDATE student SET A = 'P' WHERE `date` = '2012-05-09'";
```

---

***Inserting new records into same table***

This is not allowed to do immediately, so one has to use a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (A VARCHAR(1));

INSERT INTO tmp (A) 
SELECT 'P' FROM student WHERE dt = '...';

INSERT INTO student(A) 
SELECT A FROM tmp;

DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Comment: Try enter a valid date: `2012-05-08`.

Comment: Your first comment(in addition) is right.... But i did not get why we cannot query date??
* try{Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
      Connection con = (Connection)   
      DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/attendance","root", "******");
      Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();        
      String query="INSERT INTO student(A) VALUES('"+a+"') where dt='"+x+"';";stmt.executeUpdate(query); } *
This is the code.There are 2 columns called 'dt' and 'A'in table 'student'.I want to insert("p") in A where a date in dt resembles x(date from textfield)

Comment: INSERT creates a new record, so I thought you might want to change an existing record. But I'll edit the answer another time.